# How do I assemble proper uniforms for Threejs shaders?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

I am trying to figure out how to properly use Three.js' built in `ShaderChunk`s for lighting and fog and such, and I figured a good first step was to just copy one of the `ShaderLib` shaders' setup. So to start with I used:

```
customMaterial = new ShaderMaterial({
    lights: true,
    uniforms: UniformsUtils.merge( [
      UniformsLib.common,
      UniformsLib.specularmap,
      UniformsLib.envmap,
      UniformsLib.aomap,
      UniformsLib.lightmap,
      UniformsLib.emissivemap,
      UniformsLib.fog,
      UniformsLib.lights,
      {
        emissive: { value: new Color( 0x000000 ) },
        diffuse: { value: new Color( 1,1,1 ) }
      }
    ]),
    vertexShader: document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent
  })
```

Where the shader code is just directly copied from [meshlambert_vert.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r87/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshlambert_vert.glsl) and [meshlambert_frag.glsl](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r87/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshlambert_frag.glsl), and that section there is based on [this entry in the `ShaderLib`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r87/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js#L31)

However, I am rendering my test scene from two different cameras/renderers at once, and I immediately noticed an issue. Changing one camera's perspective changes the second camera's lighting angle, for objects with this `customMaterial` applied.

I assume this is due to these `UniformLib` objects being referenced elsewhere?

I'm not sure what I should be passing here instead, nor why this doesn't work but the standard material does. I guess I'm skipping a step, but I don't understand what it might be.

Here is a codepen where I have isolated the problem as much as I can. Now it is almost a direct copy of the `ShaderLib` source. At this point I'm thinking this is a pass-by-reference where it should have been a copy, somewhere inside the `WebGLRenderer`. https://codepen.io/cl4ws0n/pen/dVewdZ

For whatever its worth, I also tried adding a second scene, and moving the objects between them. That didn't fix it, nor did separate objects in separate scenes sharing the material.
[image: preview of the codepen link]

Comment: Please remove _everything_ from your live example that is unrelated to the problem -- and explain what, exactly, we are supposed to be looking at.

Comment: @WestLangley Okay I did that and updated my link. Just the bare necessities now. Please notice how the lighting on the left image, for the center cube, is wrong, when the camera angle on the right changes.

Comment: The 2nd box and LambertMaterial can be removed. Uniforms should be cloned to guarantee they are unique: `uniforms: UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms ),`, but that is not the issue since you are only using the material once. Are two renderers required to duplicate the issue?

Comment: Are you just trolling me?

Comment: I am trying to help you and figure out what is going on. Do you want help from me?

Comment: The question is already answered and you are coming up with more "improvements." The default material being there is key for the visual comparison. UniformUtils.merge calls clone itself. Two renders are obviously needed because that is where the problem arises. If you spent half as much time thinking about the question as you did its format you would have known all of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matjaz Drolc indicated with his comments, this is a bug in three r87. The `needsUpdate` flags are not functioning properly for `ShaderMaterials`. You can force an update before each render pass in my codepen link and it will render correctly. See the fork https://codepen.io/cl4ws0n/pen/qPYwzp

I have made an issue on the repo, if anyone would like to track it's progress it can be found [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/12383).

Answer (score 1):

WebGLRenderer has some hardcoded logic for certain materials. In this case it's looking for a flag called isMeshLambertMaterial: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r87/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L1780

So try setting `isMeshLambertMaterial: true, isMeshBasicMaterial: false` in your material.

Comment: I think you're on the right track there but I am getting an error now, at SingleUniform.setValue3fv "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined" ...

Comment: Probably you need set most of these properties as well: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r87/src/materials/MeshLambertMaterial.js#L44

Comment: That isnt it, either. I don't think this is the issue, anymore. I think its something to do with ShaderMaterials uniforms not being updated properly between renderers

Comment: https://codepen.io/cl4ws0n/pen/dVewdZ I have isolated the problem further if you want to try yourself

Comment: I traced it down to this line: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r87/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.js#L1458
It is another difference with how THREE.js's own shaders are handled (a few lines above the marked line)

Internal `needsUpdate` flags on uniforms will leak between renderers because of this.